# Head Detached warning in Travis-CI when deploying to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github, travis-ci

Why am I getting a 'Head Detached' warning in Travis-CI build logs after deploying to Heroku:
https://travis-ci.org/CenTexDevs/somewherebetweenus-mobile-web/builds/44529101 .

My .travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '0.10'
before_script:
  - 'gem update --system'
  - 'gem install compass'
  - 'npm install -g bower grunt-cli'
  - 'bower install'

deploy:
- provider: heroku
```

Comment: I know this is an old question. But I really hope that's not your actual API key.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the following line to your deploy configuration.

> Set `skip_cleanup` to true to prevent Travis CI from deleting your build artifacts.

```
deploy:
  ...
  skip_cleanup: true
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: For future reference: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/